# Not able to access env variables inside react app

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am creating MERN application and using env file but I am not able to access env variable inside react application , below is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar';

import "./app.css";

import TopBar from './components/topbar/Topbar';
import Home from './pages/home/Home';
import AdminUsersList from './pages/adminusers/AdminUsersList';

function App() {
  return (

    

    <Router>
      <TopBar />
      <div className="container">
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/users' element={<AdminUsersList/>} />
        </Routes>
        <h1>Hello {process.env.MONGO_URI}</h1>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Want to access env variable inside function and class component of react.

Comment: where did you set the variables

Comment: need to restart the application after adding a variable in .env file use "REACT_APP_" before the variable name if you create react application using "create-react-app". PS: environment variable are visible in client side.

Comment: I already restarted it many times.

Answer (score 2):

we must prefix the environment variables for class and function component with `REACT_APP_....` but in server side rendering we not need to prefix it with REACT_APP words.

you should change the `.env` variable to `REACT_APP_MONGO_URI: your mongo uri` and use it inside class and function component as `<h1>Hello {process.env.REACT_APP_MONGO_URI}</h1>`.

Answer (score 1):

You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

---

Here is the React [Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)